# SVG covers: which size must be used?

Tags: cover, svg

I'm planning to convert some books I wrote to the ebook format.

The covers were made by me in SVG using Inkscape, without any embedded raster image, and the text is converted to paths, so I don't even have the need to embed fonts.

Since SVG don't have "dimensions", but rather "proportions", which width/height ratio must I use to have the better result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can only specify one size, and not have the selected image depend on the devices resolution, you best take something that is as large as the largest expected screen format. I would at least go for `758 × 1024`, but you can consult [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_readers#Electronic-paper_displays) and decide for yourself.

Scaling down is normally OK, whereas scaling up always introduces artefacts.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Since my files are "pure" SVG (no raster included) I think the artifacts issue will be avoided: once I converted a 10×15 cm image to a 4×6 meters billboard without any hassle.